# Compose key not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, suspend, ibus, compose-key

The compose key completely stopped working for me in Ubuntu 18.04 a couple of months ago. It’s happened before, but there has usually been a way of getting it to work again (e.g. restarting ibus), but this time I can’t get it to work at all.

Previously, I thought it was connected with resuming from suspend as a new session or a reboot would (mostly, but not always) bring it back, but now it seems gone for good.

How can I get it back/diagnose this?

Other answers here seem to be about other versions or `xim` (which I don’t think I’ve used in this 18.04 install) or rely on answers with no explanation. The main [bug report that’s mentioned](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1573755) is also about `xim` and has a very high signal to noise ratio - many different situations and solutions are mentioned, including installing `ibus`.

Why does Ubuntu in particular have such a problem with it? I’ve had it happen once or twice in Solus, but I’ve not had it completely stop working.

Comment: this sounds so much like a hardware wear&tear issue, what can you give us to disproove this?

Comment: I was going to say “**(1)** the fact that it does not happen with other Linux installations and **(2)** that it happens with other keyboards” but I thought I should double check. After plugging in another keyboard, compose is back and now works with the first keyboard again (even after suspend).

Comment: This is a Microsoft Sculpt wireless keyboard and it occurs to me now that one of the reasons I stopped using the wireless mouse (apart from it being a weird blob) is that after suspend I would have to unplug and replug the dongle to get scrolling to work properly. So maybe this is actually some kind of USB issue. I’d much prefer a wired keyboard, but after years of using a MS Natural keyboard (discontinued) everything else feels wrong and the Sculpt is the closest to that layout.